# How to automate excel format API response using rest assure?

Tags: api

Am automation a API with which is giving .xls response. But while reading body as string and getting box characters . Could some one please help me to read the charaters or store it as .xls file .Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
   Httprequest.Header(“Token”,      xYZXxxx).header(“SessionKey”,Xxxxxx),header(“ContentType”,Xxxx);
   Requestspecification       httpRequest=Null:
   Response=HttpRequest.get():
   Responsecode= response. Status code;
     ResponseValue=Response.Getbody.asstring():
```

Output:

```
ResponseCode: 200
ResponseValue= Box Characters(The output is .xls file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to save the excel format API response. Find solution below.
Code:

```
response=httpRequest.get();
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("c:/Folder1/test.xls"),response.body().asByteArray());
```